# Table not being created in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I did an install of laravel 5.5 and php 7.1,
I got no errors and composer and the laravel 5.5 installed successfully.
I created a migration for a users_profile for my project then added a few columns to the migration like so.

```
$table->string('email',100)->unique();
$table->string('profile_pic')->nullable();
```

When i run `php artisan migrate` i get an error that `call to undefined function nullable()` and again `Call to undefined function unique()`.

All the errors are presided by `Symphony\component\debug\exeption\FatalThrowableError`.

What could be the problem, all the functions am using follow laravel docs guidelines.

Comment: can you paste all your migration file?

Comment: also, try with `php artisan migrate -vvv` to see where the error is occuring

Comment: @Sletheren I have multiple migration files that am trying to migrate..i have realized that one of my migration files had a syntax error, and the error was coming from that specific file.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit Thanks, i spotted the file with the error. It was a syntax error in a different migration file

Comment: @pickmanmurimi Welcome